# Set image array to image view

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When you have an array of images that are already in your Assets.xcassets folder, like so:

```
imageArray = ["background-1 (dragged).tiff", "background-2 (dragged).tiff", "background-3 (dragged).tiff", "background-4 (dragged).tiff", "background-5 (dragged).tiff",  "background-6 (dragged).tiff", "background-7 (dragged).tiff"]
```

And you want to display the images in an image view, you can do it like this.

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.object(at: index))")
return imageView
```

However, I am creating an app where the user has to put in their own images and I have the images stored in firebase. So I have this array

```
imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive]
```

But, I can't use

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.object(at: index))")
```

because the images are not stored in my Assets.xcassets folder. How will I set the imageView.image to the array I have?

I tried this:

```
 imageView.image = UIImage(imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive])
        return imageView
```

But it didn't work. Can someone please point me to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of images is small, storing them in the app's `Documents` directory is the way to go for this. Then you can store the path in a `UserDefaults` key to be retrieved later. Both of these are persistent.

With this method you will need to convert the image to `NSData` and then write it to a file in the `Documents` directory. Then when loading it, you will have to use the `UIImage` initializer that has an NSData object as a parameter.

If the user is able to upload a variable amount of images however, then this method is unwise, and CoreData is a better option.

Comment: I don't think storing the images in the app's document directory is the way to go because the app would ideally generate thousands and thousands of pictures.  Is there no other way to set my imageview to display the array of images in my imageArray? @rikola